# Insert from select queries in MySQL 5.5 InnoDB

Tags: mysql, concurrency

I have a query.

```
INSERT INTO users_resources_locks (resource_id, user_id)
SELECT resources.id, 123 FROM resources
LEFT JOIN users_resources_locks
    ON resources.id = users_resources_locks.resource_id
WHERE users_resources_locks.id IS NULL;
```

Table users_resources_locks has unique index on column resource_id.

Could concurrent query write into users_resources_locks between INSERT and SELECT part of my query?

For example is timeline below possible in repeatable read isolation level?

```
1) My query selects ((1, 123), (2, 123), (3, 123)).
2) Concurent query writes into users_resources_locks values ((1, 54321), (2, 54321)) and commits trasaction.
3) My query writes into users_resources_locks values ((1, 123), (2, 123), (3, 123)) and commits transaction fails because of unique constraint.
```

Answer (score 1):

NO, per my knowledge an DML statement like `INSERT` takes an exclusive record level implicit lock and so while one insert is in progress another `INSERT/UPDATE` can't go through. It depends on `Reader/Writer` locks and DB engine checks on lock compatibility.

```
Read Lock - R
Write Lock - W
```

With this a `RW / WR/ RR` are all compatible locks since read needs a shared lock (again depends on `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` though) but a `WW` is a non-compatible lock always.

Also, if your `ID` column is a primary key or any key column like unique key then there is no way it can get duplicated.

Comment: Yes, there are unique index. And i worry about IntegrityError when i execute my query (query has inner join into table users_resources_locks with IS NULL check, so i ensure that selected rows are not locked before). Please see updated query.

Comment: Your query is bit weird like if `resource_id` is not present then the `INNER JOIN` make no sense at all and moreover for a inner join why you need null checks.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Left join.

Comment: I have updated third part of timeline. Possible now answer is Yes.